# math operation in array of number in bash..?

Tags: linux, arrays, bash

How to make **bash** script to **take input (numbers) from user** and then calculating **SUM**, **AVERAGE** of those numbers..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this small script may do the thing for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
n='0'
s='0'
c='0'
while [ $n != "x" ]
do
    s=$(( $n+$s ))
    c=$(( $c+1 ))
    echo -n "give number pls [ENTER] (Press 'x' to exit and see result):";
    read n;
done
echo "SUM:$s"
echo "AVG:$(( $s/($c-1) ))"
```

execution and output:

```
kent$  bash math.sh
give number pls [ENTER] (Press 'x' to exit and see result):7
give number pls [ENTER] (Press 'x' to exit and see result):8
give number pls [ENTER] (Press 'x' to exit and see result):9
give number pls [ENTER] (Press 'x' to exit and see result):x
SUM:24
AVG:8
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you want to get the numbers from the user, but you can use awk inside a bash script:

Try something like this:

`awk '{ s += $1 } END { print "sum: ", s, " average: ", s/NR }' <filename>`

This will add up and average numbers in the first column of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Bash only allows integer arithmetic, so the best I can offer in pure bash is:

```
while read; do
    count=$((count+1))
    sum=$((sum+REPLY))
done
echo "Sum is $sum, value count is $count, average is $((sum/count))"
```

This will calculate the average using integral division (rounding down to nearest whole number).

For floating-point solution, I suggest `awk`, like in mdarwin's answer.